# CSS animation works in Chrome and Safari, but not in Firefox and Internet Explorer

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox

I have a simply css animation running on my  website which should simply fade in various sections of my webpage at different times. Unfortunately, this aspect of my page works only in chrome and Safari, but not in Firefox and IE.
   After doing a little research, I included unit values for the fade timeframes, but this resulted in no improvement. Here is the following css:

```
a {
   text-decoration: none; color: #FFFFFF; position: relative;
   transition: all 0.25s linear;
   -moz-transition: all 0.25s linear;
   -webkit-transition: all 0.25s linear;
   -o-transition: all 0.25s linear;
}


/*Animations*/
@-webkit-keyframes FADEY {
   0% { opacity: 0; }
   100% { opacity: 1; }
}

.intro {
   -webkit-animation-name: FADEY;
   -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
   -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
   -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
 }


[role="article"] {
   -webkit-opacity: 0;
   -webkit-animation-name: FADEY;
   -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
   -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
   -webkit-animation-delay: 0.5s;
   -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
   -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
}


.design-selection, .design-archives {
   -webkit-opacity: 0;
   -webkit-animation-name: FADEY;
   -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
   -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
   -webkit-animation-delay: 1s;
   -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
   -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
}
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks,
choltz

Comment: Include all browser prefixes everywhere, not just -webkit-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You currently have the Webkit's vendor prefix for for animation, `-webkit`. This is why it only works in Webkit-based browsers such as Chrome and Safari. For older versions of Firefox, you need to add `-moz-` as well. Current Firefox and current Internet Explorer just use the real version, `animation` with no prefix.

```
.intro {
   -webkit-animation-name: FADEY;
   -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
   -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
   -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
   -moz-animation-name: FADEY;
   -moz-animation-duration: 1s;
   -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
   -moz-animation-iteration-count: 1;
   animation-name: FADEY;
   animation-duration: 1s;
   animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
   animation-iteration-count: 1;
 }
```

You can also write out the CSS shorthand, to minimize the lines of code:

```
-webkit-animation:FADEY 1s 1 ease-in-out;
-moz-animation:FADEY 1s 1 ease-in-out;
animation:FADEY 1s 1 ease-in-out;
```

Comment: Should also add `animation`, without any prefixes.

Comment: Thanks. Additionally, to OP, here is info about browser support: http://caniuse.com/css-animation